# Issue with creating instances of a class in java

Tags: java, oop, instantiation

I am trying to make a "Racing Simulator" in which vehicles are created and compared. It includes a class where vehicles are defined and a main class where their speeds are compared. When I create two instances of Vehicle and use my getSpeed method on both instances, the speeds are the same. Any idea why?

Main:

```
public class Main {

    static Vehicle bike, jeep;
    //static Race race;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        bike = new Vehicle(4000, 20, 30.5, "bike");
        jeep = new Vehicle(3000, 12, 9.8, "Jeep");
        //race = new Race(bike, jeep, 0);
        System.out.println("Bike: " + bike.getTopSpeed() + " Jeep: " + jeep.getTopSpeed());
    }
}
```

Vehicle:

```
public class Vehicle {

    static int _weight, _topSpeed;
    static double _zeroToSixty;
    static String _vehicleName;

    public Vehicle(int weight, int topSpeed, double zeroToSixty, String vehicleName) {
        _weight = weight;
        _topSpeed = topSpeed;
        _zeroToSixty = zeroToSixty;
        _vehicleName = vehicleName;
    }

    public static void setVehicleName(String name) {
        _vehicleName = name;
    }

    public static void setWeight(int weight) {
        _weight = weight;
    }

    public static void setTopSpeed(int topSpeed) {
        _weight = topSpeed;
    }

    public static void setZeroToSixty(double zeroToSixty) {
        _zeroToSixty = zeroToSixty;
    }

    public static String getVehicleName() {
        return _vehicleName;
    }

    public static int getWeight() {
        return _weight;
    }

    public static int getTopSpeed() {
        return _topSpeed;
    }

    public static double getZeroToSixty() {
        return _zeroToSixty;
    }
}
```

The output of main is:

"Bike: 12 Jeep: 12"

Comment: `_topSpeed` is `static` hence the issue. remove the `static` modifier from the variable declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the fields as `static`. That means that the field is *shared* between all instances of the class. As the last value assigned to 
`_topSpeed` is 12 (from the second call to the constructor), this is the value you see for both instances of the class.

If you want each instance to have its own `_topSpeed` , you should drop the `static`qualifier. This would suffice:

```
int _weight, _topSpeed;
double _zeroToSixty;
String _vehicleName;
```

As a final commentary, it usually a good idea to declare the fields as `private` unless you really need them to have another type of access. So you would typically write:

```
private int _weight;
private int _topSpeed;
private double _zeroToSixty;
private String _vehicleName;
```

Having each field in its own line also helps to seethe whole declaration of each field.

Answer (score 1):

static fields exist only once per ClassLoader.
Convert your static fields to instance fields and you should be fine.

If you want to, you can keep the variables in your main class static, but all variables in the Vehicle class need to lose the `static` keyword

Comment: per ClassLoader? are you referring to the fact that if you load the same Class from different ClassLoaders they are considered different? Or is there any other conideration in effect? Just curious

Comment: @gpeche yes, but it's pretty hard to get into the situation where that is an issue. Here's an artificial scenario: https://ideone.com/e8z2Sv

Answer (score 1):

Each vehicle instance should have its own name, top speed, weight, etc. In other words, they should be declared instance variables, not static.

Change the following:

```
static int _weight, _topSpeed;
static double _zeroToSixty;
static String _vehicleName;
```

to

```
int _weight, _topSpeed;
double _zeroToSixty;
String _vehicleName;
```

Also, as a good practice, use a scope qualifier of `private` for these.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use

```
this._topSpeed()
```

And use normal variables, not static.
And why do you use an underscore?

Answer (score 0):

You have static variables for features that should be unique to each vehicle object. Static makes it a property of the class as opposed to the object. Making those instance variables should help solve your problem.